# The replacement operator -> and :> and pattern

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I'm confused by the difference between two replacement operators `->` and `:>`, and their relation with the dummy variable (pattern). For example, the first replacement in following code gives an unexpected result.

```
Clear[Ei]
Ei[k_][q_] := Table[n^k, {n, 1, 4}]

Ei[2] /. {Ei[n_] -> Ei[n][q]} (* gives the unexpected {1, 4, 27, 256} *)

Ei[2] /. {Ei[n_] :> Ei[n][q]} (* gives {1, 4, 9, 16} *)

Ei[2] /. {Ei[nn_] -> Ei[nn][q]} (* gives {1, 4, 9, 16} *)

Ei[2] /. {Ei[nn_] :> Ei[nn][q]} (* gives {1, 4, 9, 16} *)
```

A snapshot follows,

[image]

I wonder what's going on in, for example, **the 1st and the 3rd code**? The 2nd and 4th seem most understandable for a human being.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Try using `Clear["Globals`*"]` to be sure that no variable has an unwanted value.

Comment: @DanielHuber After quitting Mathematica and using a new notebook to run the codes, the above results remains. My Mathematica is of Mac version 12.0.0.0

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken, I can reproduce it. The error is created when you use `-> ` Then the right hand side is evaluated despite n not having a value. But now comes the real bug: `Ei[n][q]` where n and q do not have values. This evaluates to: `Table[n^k, {n, 1, 4}]` what is: `{1^1,2^2,3^3,4^4}`

Comment: It seems to me that the only "unexpected" result is the first. If you try enclosing that calculation in `Trace`, you'll see that the code ends up calculating `n^n` in that case, hence the result. My general approach is the following: if I have a named pattern in the left hand side of a replacement rule, then I use `RuleDelayed`. I can't think of a case where this got me into trouble; on the other hand, using plain  `Rule` in those cases can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @MarcoB @Daniel Thanks for the explanation. Indeed I have always been using `:>` instead of `->`, until my friend sent me a code with `->` and things went off rail.

Comment: @MarcoB Having come to `RuleDelayed` way too late in life, I appreciate your rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `->` versus `:>` but the way in which the variable `n` is treated as a local symbol in `Table`. As stated in the documentation, scoping in `Table` is akin to `Block`.

For example

```
f1[k_] := Block[{n}, Table[n^k, {n, 1, 4}]]
f2[k_] := Module[{n}, Table[n^k, {n, 1, 4}]]
```

is such that

```
{f1[n], f2[n]}
```

evaluates to

> {{1, 4, 27, 256}, {1, 2^n, 3^n, 4^n}}

Note how the `Module` treats the symbol `n` closer to what one would expect from a local variable. For comparison

```
g1[k_] := Block[{n}, n^k]
g2[k_] := Module[{n}, n^k]
```

are such that

```
{g1[n], g2[n]}
```

evaluates to

> {n^n, n$20657^n}

See how `Module` will first replace `n` by a "local" unique symbol before evaluation whereas `Block` will keep `n` in the "global" scope? I personally find those behaviors to be very confusing and a perennial source of really hard to find bugs.